# SQL Express 2017 Installation in Windows 7

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to install SQL Server Express 2017 in my PC (OS is Windows 7). 
But when installing attached error coming. But according to Microsoft guide I have all the HW and SW requirement in my PC.

Any idea why it is failing ?

[image]

Comment: The minimum OS required for the SQL server is Windows 8 [OS compatibility for SQL server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#TOP_Principal). Additionally, Windows 7 support ended on January 14, 2020. Find the details from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4057281/windows-7-support-ended-on-january-14-2020).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Microsoft, SQL Server 2017 requires Windows 8 or higher.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks. What about SQL Server 2016 in Windows 7?

Comment: according to the comments on the bottom of that page, people were having issues with 2016 in Win7 also. So, YMMV. Probably safer to just stick with 2014, if you are forced to be on Win7 (you probably want to look into upgrading to Win10 anyway).